# Is it possible to leverage a search engine for classification?

Tags: lucene, machine-learning, search-engine, classification

I need to classify a large amount of documents. I have seen many classical machine learning algorithms for classification. But suddenly, I ask myself, can we use search engine to do that?

My rough idea is:

We have several folders for labeled documents, such as:

- folder 1 = category 1
- folder 2 = category 2
- ...

Then for each unlabeled document, we use it as a criteria and let a search engine to search through each folder, and the one with most returned result should be the target category.

I am not sure if this is feasible. And I don't know how to create a search engine for a set of document, can Bing or Google be customized for it? Or do I need to build one with Lucene or something?

Comment: I think the real question is, why? It won't be easier to use a search engine, it won't be more accurate (I would guess a fair bit less accurate), since search and classification optimise different metrics... so while you could, why would you want to?

Comment: I am not sure if it would be less accurate. I just want to tackle the classification problem from a second perspective. And if there's a out-of-box toolbox, it could save me some effort.

Comment: I guarantee you it will be less accurate than the most basic classifiers. Text classification is the most basic problem in machine learning for NLP, most toolkits will have a 10 line demo you can run. I just don't believe it will be less effort to adapt a search engine to do classification than use a classification library (scikit-learn, nltk, mallet, weka, etc etc)

Answer (score 0):

yes, search engines store most information needed to do text classification so you can build some of the algorithms on top of them.

For Lucene/Solr, look at the work done by [this commiter](http://archive.apachecon.com/eu2012/presentations/08-Thursday/L1R-Lucene/aceu-2012-text-categorization-with-lucene-and-solr.pdf). The code is already in usable in Solr/Lucene 4.6. I have used it in one instance with good results.